# Textual representation of LaBSE preprocessor output?

Tags: tokenize, encoder, tensorflow-hub

I use the following model to tokenize sentences from multiple languages:
https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-cmlm/multilingual-preprocess/2

Which, for the following input:

```py
"I wish you a pleasant flight and a good meal aboard this plane."
```

outputs the following tokens:

```json
[101, 146, 34450, 15100, 170, 147508, 48088, 14999, 170, 17072, 66369, 351617, 15272, 69746, 119, 102]
```

From this output, I would like to recover a textual representation of the tokens. Something like :

```py
[START, I, wish, ..., plane, .]
```

So far I've been looking for the token<=>text mapping, but found resources mostly about BERT, which has got several MONO-lingual models, while I want to stay language-agnostic.

Anyclue about how to do that ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default cache location for the `google/universal-sentence-encoder-cmlm/multilingual-preprocess/2` model is `/tmp/tfhub_modules/8e75887695ac632ead11c556d4a6d45194718ffb` ([more on caching](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching)). In the `assets` directory, you'll find `cased_vocab.txt`, which is the used vocabulary:

```
!cat /tmp/tfhub_modules/.../assets/cased_vocab.txt | sed -n 102p
> [CLS]
!cat /tmp/tfhub_modules/.../assets/cased_vocab.txt | sed -n 147p
> I
!cat /tmp/tfhub_modules/.../assets/cased_vocab.txt | sed -n 34451p
> wish
...
```

Note that `sed` assumes 1-based indexing while the output of the preprocessor is 0-based.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the kind of answer I've been looking for.